# Constructing a sequence up to infinity

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, foundations

Consider the sets $x_1, x_2,x_3,\ldots$ I was wondering if we could construct a sequence of sets as follows:
\begin{equation}
x_1=\{x_2\},\;x_2=\{x_3\},\;\ldots
\end{equation}
and continue to infinity. My initial thoughts were that no, because for any $x\in x_1$, it happens that $x\in x$, given how it's constructed. And this cannot happen because of the separation axiom in ZFC. At least that's my idea.

I just don't know how to put it mathematically, or if the idea is wrong. Could anyone please help?

Comment: How do you get $x\in x$ from $x\in x_1$?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's true, but it would be an element infinitely contained in different sets (like being self similar). I don't know if I'm making much sense.

Comment: No, $x\in{x_1}$ does not imply $x\in{x}.$ Also, I am not sure your sequence is even well defined. The recursion you have proposed is $x_n=\{x_{n+1}\}$, and it is unclear to me that this recursion is meaningful. Perhaps you meant you recursion to be $x_{n+1}=\{x_n\}.$ This makes much more sense, and this is a recursion that does have a name in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity

Comment: @Angel In my notes, I have the former sequence, but I don't understand it either. What is that other sequence?

Comment: @GreekCorpse The terms of the other sequence are known as the Zermelo ordinals or the Zermelo natural numbers. They are an alternative set-theoretic construction of the natural numbers, less common to the Von Neumann ordinals or Von Neumann natural numbers.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful if I knew what $x_0$ in the recursion you provide. Then maybe one can make sense of the recursion... sort of, but not really. The problem is that, suppose that $x_2=\{\{\}\}$ as an example. Then $x_1=\{\{\{\}\}\}$ by the very recursion. But this recursion terminates: it does not generate a sequence. This is because since $\{\{\}\}=x_2=\{x_3\},$ one has $x_3=\{\}$ by the axiom of extensionality. But there does not exist any $y$ such that $y\in{x_3}$, so $x_4$ is simply undefined. Rather, it is better to say: there is no $x_4$ to find.

Comment: The definition works finitely if, for example for $n=3$, we say that $x_1=\{\{x_3\}\}$, $x_2=\{x_3\}$(, $x_3=x_3$). That's why we are asking whether or not it can be extended to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Regularity axiom prohibits sequences such as you imagine, more accurately described as running *down to infinity*. Such a sequence would be an infinite descending $\in$ chain, thus $\{x_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ would have no $\in$-minimal element.

Notice that if $a = \{b\}$, then $b = \bigcup a$. (The converse does *not* hold!) Starting with any $x_0$, you can define a sequence of iterated unions:

$$
x_{n+1} = \bigcup x_n.
$$
By Regularity, eventually $x_n = \emptyset$, so of course $\emptyset = x_{n+1} \notin x_n = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see the relation of ''$a=\{b\}$ implies $b=\bigcup a$'' off the bat, so it helped a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I could see it was perplexing you that the thing being defined appeared only on the RHS!

Comment: However you can work in [Non-well founded set theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonwellfounded-set-theory/), which allows all manner of what are called co-inductive definitions. An instance of the kind of  set that you are interested in would be defined by $x = \{x\}$.